# Is coin tossing a Markov process?

Tags: probability, markov-process

When we toss an unbiased coin, the probability of observing both heads and tails is 1/2. I take that to mean that over a really large number of coin tosses the number of times the coin will turn heads will be almost equal* to the number of times the coin will turn tails.

My question is, if we witness a series of coin tosses that happens to have many more number of, say heads, than tails then will we not expect the upcoming coin tosses to be 'mean-reverting' i.e. more inclined to produce tails than heads - only in order to maintain the definition of probability being 1/2 as per the previous paragraph?

I think what I am really asking is whether an unbiased coin-tossing is a Markov process. I would add that if it is, then my understanding of why the probability of heads/tails is 1/2 is wrong.

[*] - If not, then we need more coin tosses such that the ratio of number of heads (or tails) to the total number of coin tosses approaches 1/2 as the number of coin tosses approaches infinity.

Comment: The answer to the question in your second paragraph is "no", as the coin has no memory of what it has shown before.  Your assumption is known as the [Gambler's fallacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambler's_fallacy)

Comment: For a fair coin, the expected difference (in absolute or root-mean-square senses) between the *numbers* of heads and tails increases when the number of tosses increases, though the expected difference between the *proportions* of heads and tails decreases when the number of tosses increases.  So you need to consider what "almost equal" really means

Comment: @Henry Wouldn't a problem like this pose an "inverse" Gambler's fallacy? Instead we should consider if the coin is biased, i.e. $p \neq 0.5$.

Comment: @O.VonSeckendorff: Perhaps.  If you tossed a coin several times, and it showed "heads" each time, how many tosses would it take before you checked carefully that it did not have two heads?

Answer (score 1):

Intuition can be gained from the fact that these averages are completely determined by the tail values, and not the first few terms. That is, for **any** fixed $k∈\Bbb N$ and **any** finite number of terms $b_1,…,b_k$ (even if $b_i ≠ a_j$ for every $i,j$)

$$ \lim_{n→∞} \frac{1}{n}(a_1+…+a_n) =  \lim_{n→∞} \frac{1}{n}(b_1+…+b_k+a_{k+1} + … + a_n) $$

Hence, there is no need for the $a_j$s to 'correct the bad behaviour of $b_i$s'; the $b_i$s simply don't matter in the long run.

Comment: Extending the RHS in your equality above (replacing $a_{k+1}...a_{k+m}$ with $c_1...c_m$)
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n}(b_1+...+b_k+c_1+...+c_m+a_{k+m+1}+...+a_n)
$$
what I am really intrigued about is, would we not have more to say about the expected values of $c_1...c_m$ conditional upon observed sequence $b_1...b_k$ which behaved 'badly'? Agreed, that in the long run they all average out, but please help me grasp why in the immediate vicinity of the badly behaving sub-sequence there is no 'attempt' to correct it.

Comment: There is no reason to suppose mean reversion; in the standard frequentist model of a coin, the value 1/2 has nothing to do with any finite string precisely because of the above identity and what it means to be a 'long time(limit) average'. You are free to create your own model random variable but it won't be what people refer to as unbiased coin tossing.